# Boto: What is the best way to check if a CloudFormation stack is exists?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cloudformation

What is the best way to check if a CloudFormation stack exists and is not in a broken state using Boto? By broken I mean failed and rollback states.

I don't want to use a `try/except` solution, because boto logs it as an error, and in my scenario it's going to send the exception log to an alarm system.

---

At the moment I have the following solutions:

1) Use [`boto.cloudformation.connection.CloudFormationConnection.describe_stacks()`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudformation.html#boto.cloudformation.connection.CloudFormationConnection.describe_stacks)

```
valid_states = '''\
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
CREATE_COMPLETE
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS
UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS
UPDATE_COMPLETE'''.splitlines()

def describe_stacks():
    result = []
    resp = cf_conn.describe_stacks()
    result.extend(resp)
    while resp.next_token:
        resp = cf_conn.describe_stacks(next_token=resp.next_token)
        result.extend(resp)
    return result


stacks = [stack for stack in describe_stacks() if stack.stack_name == STACK_NAME and stack.stack_status in valid_states]
exists = len(stacks) >= 1
```

This is slow because I have lots of stacks.

---

2) Use [`boto.cloudformation.connection.CloudFormationConnection.list_stacks()`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudformation.html#boto.cloudformation.connection.CloudFormationConnection.list_stacks)

```
def list_stacks(filters):
    result = []
    resp = cf_conn.list_stacks(filters)
    result.extend(resp)
    while resp.next_token:
        resp = cf_conn.list_stacks(filters, next_token=resp.next_token)
        result.extend(resp)
    return result

stacks = [stack for stack in list_stacks(valid_states) if stack.stack_name == STACK_NAME]
exists = len(stacks) >= 1
```

This takes forever, because summaries are kept for 90 days and I have lots of stacks.

---

Question: What is the **ideal** solution to check if a given stack exists and is not in a failure or rollback state?

Comment: It would be really nice if list_stacks accepted a list of stack_names filter. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @bdrx: No, I didn't and I haven't look for another solution since the week I posted this question.

Answer (score 12):

I implemented the following which works:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

def stack_exists(name, required_status = 'CREATE_COMPLETE'):
    try:
        data = client.describe_stacks(StackName = name)
    except ClientError:
        return False
    return data['Stacks'][0]['StackStatus'] == required_status
```

I didn't find any of the previous solutions complete, nor is there any quick way of doing it with boto3 so I created the above.

Answer (score 4):

From the boto docs:

> describe_stacks(stack_name_or_id=None, next_token=None)
>
> Returns the description for the specified stack; if no stack name was specified, then it returns the description for all the stacks created.
>
> Parameters:   stack_name_or_id (string) – The name or the unique identifier associated with the stack.

Since you know the stack name, you can use `describe_stacks(stack_name_or_id=STACK_NAME)`. That should speed things up for you.

Comment: If the stack doesn't exist, it raises an Exception, and as I said, it's not enough to use a try/except because boto logs that as an error, and my alert system gets notified if it sees an error log. Thank you, but it's not enough.

Comment: @HugoTavares. to solve this I use `waiter` to wait for `stack_exists` with 1 attempt only (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html?highlight=describe_stacks#CloudFormation.Waiter.StackExists) and catch  for `TooManyAttemptsError`

Comment: In Case anyone else tries to figure it out.. The correct error is botocore.exceptions.WaiterError in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but someone asked if there was a solution to it just a couple of weeks ago, so here goes...

If you read the boto3 docs, it mentions deleted stacks quite frequently. In order to do this, you **have** to use the full stack ID. You can't use the stack name. This is because the only thing truly unique about the stack is the ID.

Example:

```
resource = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
status = resource.Stack('id:of:stack').stack_status
```

The only time this will return an exception is if that stack ID doesn't exist.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would check via the paginator combined with [ListStacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListStacks.html) API call because it might be possible my lambda or I doesn't have permissions for `cloudformation` if that happens, I should return relevant information instead of saying stack doesn't exist.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

cfn = boto3.client('cloudformation')
def stack_exists(stack_name: str, stack_status: str) -> bool:
    try:
        paginator = cfn.get_paginator('list_stacks')
        response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
        for page in response_iterator:
            for stack in page['StackSummaries']:
                if stack_name == stack.get('StackName') and stack.get('StackStatus') != stack_status:
                    return True
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.exception(f'Client error while checking stack : {e}')
        raise
    except Exception:
        logger.exception('Error while checking stack')
        raise
    return False
```

Or if we don't want to iterate over all the stacks:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

cfn = boto3.client('cloudformation')
def stack_exists(stack_name: str, required_status='DELETE_COMPLETE'):
    try:
        stacks_summary = cfn.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)
        stack_info = stacks_summary.get('Stacks')[0]
        return stack_name == stack_info.get('StackName') and stack_info.get('StackStatus') != required_status
    except ClientError as e:
        stack_not_found_error = f'Stack with id {stack_name} does not exist'
        error_received = e.response('Error')
        error_code_received = error_received.get('Code')
        error_message_received = error_received.get('Message')
        if error_code_received == 'ValidationError' and error_message_received == stack_not_found_error:
            return True
        logger.exception(f'Client error while describing stacks: {e}')
        raise
    except Exception:
        logger.exception('Error while checking stack')
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this will be to split this into two separate problems:

1. Find out which stacks don't exist.
2. Find out which stacks are in an error state.

Might look something like this:

```
failure_states = ['CREATE_FAILED', ... ]
stack_names = ['prod', 'dev', 'test']

c = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region(region)
existing_stacks = [s.stack_name for s in c.describe_stacks()]
nonexistent_stacks = set(stack_names) - set(existing_stacks)
error_stacks = c.list_stacks(stack_status_filters=failure_states)
```

You may have many more stacks then I do so maybe you need to use `next_token` to paginate, which would be a bit of a hassle. However, you can see that both operations can be done with a single request each and will not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @liyan-chang, but the answer to your first problem is infinite. My code doesn't know anything about the existing stacks, and I want to find out if a given stack exists. What is the *best way* to check if stack "ABC" exists in CloudFormation, through Boto?

Comment: 'ABC' in [s.stack_name for s in c.describe_stacks()]

Comment: But this may be slow if there are many stacks... I had this solution in the question text.

Comment: Ah. You're in a rock and a hard place. If you can't list all the stacks, then you have to try/except the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can silence the Boto logger by setting its level above ERROR. This will let you capture the exception without the logging alarm:

```
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions
import logging

cf = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['boto3'].setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['botocore'].setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
try:
    stack.Stack('foo').stack_status
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
    logging.info('stack doesnt exist')

logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['boto3'].setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['botocore'].setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```